# Can Apple delete an app installed via iTunes or the App Store without your permission?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, apple-inc

I had always thought the answer to this was no. I have an app that was pulled from the iOS App Store (VLC) still on my non-jailbroken phone and thought this was proof that Apple can't remote wipe an app. But I just heard a claim that they *can* remote wipe apps installed via their app purchase portals if they choose.

Is this true? True for just iOS apps or just App Store apps?

Comment: you should not confuse 'remotely delete an app' and 'remove an app from sale'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's true [Apple **can** remotely delete apps](http://www.macrumors.com/2008/08/06/apples-ability-to-deactivate-malicious-app-store-apps/). This is a failsafe in case a nefarious app accidentally makes it past the review process. Not sure about Mac App store, I doubt the ability exists there. It's a different installation/update process.

I don't think it's been done before, and I wouldn't worry about it. It's a good thing. I would want an app that say sniffs my credit card numbers or is actually a trojan horse of some kind to be removed from my iPhone post haste.

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be possible. 
You never know until it happens. If I were in a company that screened all sold applications so closely, then I'd keep the option available. Someone could slip a harmful app through the screening process, and if you could remote wipe all the bad apps, then you wouldn't loose rep for it. :D

But as you say yourself, they haven't deleted apps like VLC, I have it too on my iOS. 
Besides, if you sync apps to your itunes, you always have a hard copy of them in your iTunes library, so don't know if wiping would help :D

Comment: you should not confuse 'remotely delete an app' and 'remove an app from sale'